# Login test using Taurus

Tags: jmeter, taurus

Test login action using Taurus

```
execution:
  -
    concurrency: 5
    ramp-up: 5
    hold-for: 1m
    scenario: Buyer-logs-in


scenarios:
  Buyer-logs-in:
    variables:
      baseurl: http://localhost:3000
    default-address: ${baseurl}
    data-sources:
      - path: './login.csv'
        delimeter: ','
        variable-names: userName, password
    keepalive: true
    retrieve-resources: false

    requests:
      - url: 'http://localhost:3000/login'
        label: login
        method: POST
        body:
          user[email]: {userName}
          user[password]:  {password}
        assert:
          - contains:
              - 200
            subject: http-code

      - url: 'http://localhost:3000/action'
        label: page1
        method: GET
        assert:
          - contains:
              - 200
            subject: http-code
```

This is my sample Taurus code to simulate login and measure peformance.

1. In my app, only one user can login at a time and my csv file has 2 users. The test still works when I set a concurrency of 5 and Taurus says 5 users logged in. How is that possible. When the same user logs in again he will be kicked out of the first browser where he logged in. So with 2 user logins, how does Tuarus simulate 5 users?
2. With that asked, does taurus really login using the credentials i give in the csv file? Or should I use selenium/Taurus to simulate it?
3. What really confused me was when I deleted all users in csv file, the test still did not gave me 200 for the login and page1.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify `executor` Taurus will use [`jmeter` as default](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/), it means that your YAML config will be translated into [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) test plan

You can see the generated test plan by running `bzt your-test.yaml -gui` command

1. `data-sources` is translated to [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) which looks like:

   [image]

   it means that each thread (virtual user) will pick up the new value from the CSV file each iteration like:

   - virtual user 1 - iteration 1 - 1st line
   - virtual user 2 - iteration 1 - 2nd line
   - virtual user 3 - iteration 1 - 1st line
   - virtual user 1 - iteration 2 - 2nd line
   - etc.
2. I don't think so, you're reading the credentials from the CSV file but not using it anywhere, the correct syntax for [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) is `${variable_name_here}` so you need to set the login request body to:

   ```
   user[email]: ${userName}
   user[password]:  ${password}
   ```

   as long as you properly [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) there is no need to use Selenium
3. You might be getting false positive results because your [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)  doesn't do a lot of useful job, JMeter automatically considers [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful. So instead of checking status code I would rather recommend verifying that the use is logged in, i.e. "Welcome" message is there or API response has some specific text for successful login and/or doesn't contain errors.

Comment: Thanks @dmitri. I was finally able to use Jmeter and see what you were saying. Your explanation is great.